# Unable to extract zip file using Unarchive module in ansible

Tags: ansible, zip

I got the error while unzip the zip file using unarchive module in my ansible playbook....it was working fine sometimes i am getting the Below error

> FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to find handler for \"/apps/tmp/RCB/MY_UAT_E12.07.15.1213/eBBS/E12_APP.zip\". Make sure the required command to extract the file is installed. Command \"/bin/gtar\" could not handle archive. Command \"/usr/bin/unzip\" could not handle archive."}

I use the below playbook code to do unarchive

```
unarchive:
        src: /tmp/dowload/file.zip
        dest: /tmp/extract
        copy: no
```

Is there anything to be corrected I gone through the ansible docs.....I hope i was on the right code but still getting the error...please any suggestions

Comment: `I got the error while unzip` => which is ? While your are at it can you please review your entire question and format it correctly ? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry this was the error i m getting ... In the ZIP file I have only Jar and war files.
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to find handler for \"/apps/tmp/RCB/MY_UAT_E12.07.15.1213/eBBS/E12_APP.zip\". Make sure the required command to extract the file is installed. Command \"/bin/gtar\" could not handle archive. Command \"/usr/bin/unzip\" could not handle archive."}

Comment: Please do not add the necessary info in comments: edit your question and add it there (and format code correctly looking at formating tips on the edit page). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Winzip new version. Hope this solve your issue